# Windows Task Scheduler Basic Task isn't re-loading shell script

Tags: windows, task, scheduler, git-bash

I wrote a bash script to hit our buildkite and pull down and parse the buildkite.xml and update some local files that I'm using to drive my DesktopInfo.

It mostly works except for something I discovered today when I made a change to the shell script and noticed it wasn't picked up.

My task is a Basic Task with the Action,

```
Start a program    "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c "/c/Users/Scott/src/sh/buildkite-status.sh /c/Users/Downloads"
```

With the Trigger of Daily at 8:00am and repeating every 30 minutes.

I'm outputting several files with timestamps when it runs. Like I said I made a change to the buildkite-status.sh and it wasn't reflected. I'm on Windows 11.

I would have expected that the next time the job was repeated it would read the current version of the buildkite-status.sh. Do I need to provide more to the task definition or the command line itself to get it to re-read the script?